# Push from a Modal not part of the UINavigationController

Tags: ios

I have a screen which pops up another screen as a modal. The new screen is divided into multiple container views.One of the container view contains a UITableView. I want when I select the row it pushes a new controller on the parent view controller.

Basically, I want a push segue from a modal to another modal!

UPDATE:

It is hard to explain but let me try again. I have one UIViewController (displayed as a modal) that contains 3 container views. Each container view is controlled by a separate UIViewController. Now, I want that when I click a button in one of the container views, it should replace the entire parent controller (the one that contains all three container views).

Comment: If you want to "push" that new controller on the parent controller, then it's not a modal controller. Push is a specific transition used by navigation controllers.

Comment: I have explained the question a little better!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view controller that's contained within a UINavigationController, you can access the navigation controller using

```
[self navigationController]
```

e.g.

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:someOtherController
                                       animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't have a navigation controller for my modal. Also, The tableview is part of the different view controller and is container in the parent view controller as an embedded segue.

Answer (score 0):

From one of the child view controllers, you can reference the parent with the parentViewController property. So, just do this:

```
NextController *next = [NextController alloc] init.....
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:next animated:YES completion:nil];
```